# Use SharePoint web service to return a People/Group column value

Tags: 2010, development, web-services

When I call a SharePoint web service in a .Net ASPX website, the people column returns null (Instance of the object not found).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using SPAPI.ReportSecurity;

namespace SPAPI
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CP2DataContext dc = new CP2DataContext(new Uri("http://server/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
            dc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
            var xml = dc.ReportSecurity;
            foreach (var row in xml)
            {
                Response.Write("Customer: " + row.Customer + ", ");
                Response.Write("Customer #: " + row.CustomerNumbers + "<br>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a CustomerId column in the SP list, which I didn't create...maybe it's the user profile ID. If I make a text column and manually put the domain\username as a string, there is no problem. Why is the People column null? How do I get row.Customer.username?

Answer (score 1):

You need the $expand query option for use with explicit queries using URLs, however setting up a [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as you have done should enable you to navigation properties via the [DataServiceQuery.Expand()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679728%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method.

The fact that you have a CustomerId column in the ReportSecurity proxy class of your DataServiceContext is an example of that; this contains the integer value of the user or group within the UserInformationList of your Site Collection.

Try the following:

```
var xml = dc.ReportSecurity.Expand("Customer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the $expand option to expand the person/group field values since you're using the REST API?

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Projects?$expand=Client
```

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2010Dev/Pages/REST%20APIs.aspx

Comment: CP2DataContext dc = new CP2DataContext(new Uri("http://server/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ReportSecurity?$expand=Customer"));

`Throws the error:
Expected an absolute, well formed http URL without a query or fragment.  Parameter name: serviceRoot`